# tidyr spread function won't return date

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Sorry relative R novice here trying to do more with dplyr. I have a large data frame with an id column, end (dates as POSIXct) and D (codes the outcome ~6 different types), sample here:

```
   id        end  D
 1143 1996-08-10 KT
 1148 2000-07-27 KT
 1150 2004-07-02 KT
 1158 2001-11-03 KT
```

I want to create a subset for outcome KT. Within this outcome, many id's have 1-4 outcomes with separate dates. I want to create a wide data frame that looks like this:

```
   id    datetx1    datetx2    datetx3    datetx4
 1915 2014-10-13 2014-10-18       <NA>       <NA>
 2715 2006-09-17 2006-09-17 2006-09-17 2008-02-01
 5089 2007-02-02 2007-02-11       <NA>       <NA>
 5266 2007-04-16 2010-07-14 2010-07-14       <NA>
```

I have been trying to use dplyr and tidyr with some success at going from long to wide, but am getting stuck with the dates with this approach:

```
transplant<-filter(outcomes, D == "KT") %>%
  filter(!is.na(date)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange((end)) %>%
  mutate(number = row_number()) %>%
  spread(number, date)
```

The problem is with spread, which creates numeric values in the other columns that I can’t seem to coerce into dates. I have resorted to coding the date as.character and then recoding as.Date after the spread which works but am I missing something about tidyr and date coding?

Comment: I think I had the same thing the other day. I ended up converting character to date objects. It may be worth checking news on github.

Comment: `spread` should have a `convert` argument which defaults to FALSE. Try `convert = TRUE` ?

Comment: thanks. convert = FALSE didn't work so I'll stick with coding the dates as.character

Comment: It looks like the underlying issue here has been fixed; I can't reproduce it, and the example is particularly confusing because of the use of `date` as a column, which does not exist in the sample data.

Answer (score 1):

R and `dplyr` has moved on quite a bit since this question was originally posted. `spread` has been superseded by `pivot_wider`, which is what I'll use in this answer.

```
# recreation of the data used in the question
df <- structure(list(id = c(1915, 1915, 2715, 2715, 2715, 2715, 5089, 
5089, 5266, 5266, 5266), end = structure(c(16356, 16361, 13408, 
13408, 13408, 13910, 13546, 13555, 13619, 14804, 14804), class = "Date"), 
    D = c("KT", "KT", "KT", "KT", "KT", "KT", "KT", "KT", "KT", 
    "KT", "KT")), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))


df %>%
    filter(D == "KT") %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    select(-D) %>%
    mutate(n = row_number()) %>%
    pivot_wider(values_from = end, names_from = n, names_prefix = "datetx_")
```